# Why doesn't my compiled app make fetch requests?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

I have a linux server that I configured (although I don't know if I did it right) and when I'm using the Expo Go app to send Fetch requests they are sent without a problem, but when I compile the application it's like nothing I did works, because I tried to install and correct all possible dependencies but it doesn't work
[error alert conection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6WmPr.jpg)

In my development environment I have debugged the code with responses in consoles to verify that everything is sent correctly and no error appears

I have the doubt if the error is the configuration of my server or some dependency problem since at the moment of compiling I did get a few warnings

I have tried to resolve the dependencies that it tells me are not compatible, I have read a lot of documentation to see compatible versions but I still cannot solve it, errors like these always appear
[error expo compile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M9TJP.png)

Comment: How do you run this compiled application? Can't you show full error message of the request?

Comment: @Konrad the error that comes out in my compiled app is network request failed

Comment: Can the Linux server be accessed from other networks? Is the device in the same network as the server?

Comment: @konrad Yes, the server can be accessed from other networks, I don't think the error is from cors or something similar since I enabled cors, I have the theory that the error is when compiling since I have received warnings in eas-cli that come like this



/home/expo/workingdir/build/android/app/build/generated/assets/createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets/index.android.bundle:20373:23: warning: the variable "XMLHttpRequest" was not declared in anonymous function " 520#"

[stderr] 

        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();